# Issue while calling the external api in azure datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to encode the file content to Base64, create a JSON object with this encoded content, and subsequently send this JSON as part of an external call to an API endpoint.

I am getting error DF-REST_001 - Error response from server: Some(), Status code: 415. Please check your request url and body.

Some({"OperationName":"importBulkData","DocumentContent":"ajndjnddff","ContentType":"csv","FileName":"xxx_20231206.csv","DocumentAccount":"xx$/xxx$/xx$","JobName":"/xx/zz/xx/zz/ddd/ff/xx/,Import","ParameterList":"Operations,xx,xx,ALL,N,N,N","JobOptions":"InterfaceDetails=15,EnableEvent=Y,ImportOption=Y ,PurgeOption = N,ExtractFileType=ALL"}), request method: POST)

is this failing because of some() getting added to json request?. if yes, can someone help to resolve this issue please.

Appreciate your help

Hello everyone,

I need to encode the file content to Base64, create a JSON object with this encoded content, and subsequently send this JSON as part of an external call to an API endpoint.

I created a dataflow with following steps,
[dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWSUu.png)

1. SrcInputFile - Read entire file as single column.
2. Derivingcolumns - Read the input and convert it to base64
   [Derivingcolumns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuFBy.png) 
   3)selectrequiredcolumn - Selected converted content column and src filename
   [selectrequiredcolumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WYoz.png)
   4)derivejsonbody - Forming a jsonbody to pass to external call
   [derivejsonbody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d701.png) 
   5)externalcall1 - calling the api
   [externalcall1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlewf.png)

I am getting error DF-REST_001 - Error response from server: Some(), Status code: 415. Please check your request url and body.

Some({"OperationName":"importBulkData","DocumentContent":"ajndjnddff","ContentType":"csv","FileName":"xxx_20231206.csv","DocumentAccount":"xx$/xxx$/xx$","JobName":"/xx/zz/xx/zz/ddd/ff/xx/,Import","ParameterList":"Operations,xx,xx,ALL,N,N,N","JobOptions":"InterfaceDetails=15,EnableEvent=Y,ImportOption=Y ,PurgeOption = N,ExtractFileType=ALL"}), request method: POST)

is this failing because of some() getting added to json request?. if yes, can someone help to resolve this issue please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHFov.png)

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

> DF-REST_001 - Error response from server: Some(), Status code: 415. Please check your request url and body.

The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type error signifies that the server declines to process the request due to an unsupported format in the payload, leading to the server's refusal to accept the data.

***When you set the body format in external call in mapping data flow.***

By default, **JSON** is selected. select  ***None***  instead.

- **When choosing JSON, the transformation wraps the sent body within 'SOME(jsonPayload)',** which leads to a non-standard JSON file being submitted with the request like below example.

```json
//Expected JSON body
{
    "name": "marc"
}

//Current body
SOME(
{
    "name": "marc"
})
```

If the **None** option is chosen, the payload value is configured as a string. Simultaneously, set the **Additional header** **`content-type`** header with value as `application/JSON`. ***This setup ensures that despite the payload being a string, upon submission of the request, it will be interpreted and processed as JSON data. Consequently, the system will treat the string content as a JSON object, handling it appropriately based on the specified content-type header.***

[image: Screenshot 2023-03-24 at 9 03 27 PM]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did as per your recommendations but it still gives me the same error. Can you please guide me more on this issue?
Please have a look at this picture "enter image description here" above.

Comment: can you add image of mapping ?